# Does this fail to be a category?

Tags: category-theory

I've been skimming over Aluffi's *Chapter 0* the past few days to get back to where I once was and recall everything -- and I got curious over something in Section I.3.

On pages 22-23, he introduces a category defined the following way:

> Let $\textsf{C}$ be a category. Define a new category $\textsf{C}_A$ as follows
>
> - $\text{Obj}(\textsf{C}_A)$ are morphisms $f\in \text{Hom}_\textsf{C}(Z,A)$, for any $Z \in \text{Obj}(\textsf{C})$.
> - Morphisms $f_1\to f_2$ are commutative diagrams corresponding to morphisms $\sigma: Z_1 \to Z_2$ such that $f_1 = f_2 \sigma$.

He then mostly verifies this a category (leaving some exercises for the reader). When introducing this category, he said that the way morphisms are defined here are the "most natural choice". I'm curious perhaps then if this would work as a category as well:

- $\text{Obj}(\textsf{C}^*_A)$ are morphisms $f\in \text{Hom}_\textsf{C}(Z,A)$, for any $Z \in \text{Obj}(\textsf{C})$.
- Morphisms $f_1\to f_2$ correspond to morphisms $\sigma: A \to A$ (so the diagram looks like a "U")

I don't really have a paper and pencil on me to meticulously look into this -- but it seems this satisifies almost every property of a category:

1. Every object has an identity, namely $1_A$.
2. You can compose morphisms, as they're just identities and $\textsf{C}$ is a category. (Also, wouldn't composition be commutative here?)
3. Identities respect composition.
4. Composition is associative, follows from $\textsf{C}$ being a category.

What makes me believe this isn't a category though is it fails this fifth requirement:

> $$\text{Hom}_{\textsf{C}^*_A}(A,B)\cap \text{Hom}_{\textsf{C}^*_A}(C,D)= \emptyset$$
>   unless $A=C$ and $B=D$.

Since in this category essentially every set of morphisms between objects is the set $\text{End}_\textsf{C}(A)$. So does this mean $\textsf{C}^*_A$ doesn't form a category?

Comment: What is the fifth condition? I've never seen that as an axiom of category theory. There are categories in fact in which this axiom doesn't hold (finite abelian groups)

Comment: @leibnewtz I've seen this condition before - it says that a morphism should "know" its own domain and codomain, which seems a pretty natural requirement to me. I would certainly teach my students not to call two group homomorphisms (or maps of any kind) *equal* (as functions) unless they had the same domain and codomain. But it's obviously just pedantry on some level, and I'm sure you can do plenty without it.

Comment: @Billy Oh thanks I think I misread it

Comment: @leibnewtz I actually editted it! I recalled the requirement slightly incorrectly. Turned out the fifth requirement was actually slightly stricter than what I thought it was, I thought the two sets were equal only if $A=C$ and $B=D$, meaning they can still overlap -- but it turned out the proper statement of the requirement is that the sets are _completely disjoint_ unless we have that condition. My apologies!

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Whoops, yes!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's something not written but implicit in your definition: in order for $\sigma f_1$ and $f_2$ to be equal, they must have the same domain, i.e. morphisms $f_1\to f_2$ only exist in your (prospective) category when $f_1$ and $f_2$ are both maps $Z\to A$ for the *same* $Z$.

That is, an element of $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathsf{C}^*_A}(f_1,f_2)$ is *a commutative triangle* made up of the maps $f_1: Z\to A$, $f_2: Z\to A$ and $\sigma: A\to A$ (I don't know how to draw commutative diagrams on here, so you can do it yourself!). In particular, elements of the set $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathsf{C}^*_A}(f_1,f_2)$ "remember" their domain and codomain $f_1$ and $f_2$ by definition: these elements aren't just maps $\sigma$, but maps $\sigma$ *along with* domain $f_1$ and codomain $f_2$. The domain and codomain are *built into* these commutative triangles.

In practice, people will usually write these maps as $\sigma\in \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathsf{C}^*_A}(f_1,f_2)$, but strictly speaking that's not quite true. A better notation, capturing *all* of the information in the commutative triangle, would be $(\sigma, f_1, f_2)\in\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathsf{C}^*_A}(f_1,f_2)$.

Long story short: if $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathsf{C}^*_A}(f_1,f_2)$ and $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathsf{C}^*_A}(g_1,g_2)$ intersect - say, the element $(\sigma,f_1,f_2)\in \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathsf{C}^*_A}(f_1,f_2)$ can also be written as $(\tau,g_1,g_2)\in \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathsf{C}^*_A}(g_1,g_2)$ - then *the whole commutative triangle* this element represents must be the same. That is, $\sigma = \tau, f_1 = g_1, f_2 = g_2$.

---

To address something you said about "naturality": there's nothing wrong with your category at all. I wouldn't call it "unnatural". It's just that it doesn't crop up all that often in mathematics. Aluffi's category $\mathsf{C}_A$ does crop up a lot, though; it's even got its own special name, the *slice* category. It's a particular way of viewing how objects in $\mathsf{C}$ behave "relative to" $A$. In this case, the notion of "being relative to $A$" is a part of the structure of an object $Z\to A$, and if you want to study objects with a certain standing relative to $A$, then it's *natural* to ask for the morphisms to *preserve* that structure. I think this was the sense in which Aluffi used the word.

Comment: Ahhh okay, everything you said makes perfect sense :) I realized after someones comment (I believe it was perhaps yours, it was deleted) that writing $\sigma f_1 = f_2$ is silly as the morphisms in $\textsf{C}_A^*$ weren't "closed" diagrams, as they were all "U" shaped (left and right being $Z_1 \to A$ and $Z_2 \to A$, and on the bottom, connecting the two, $A \to A$.) Anyhow, thank you for clearing up everything!

Comment: No problem. One other important comment I forgot to make: the statement at the end of your property 2 isn't correct. Maps $A\to A$ don't have to be the identity - lots of categories have plenty of nontrivial endomorphisms, and these won't commute either. But the composite of two maps $A\to A$ is still a map $A\to A$, and that's all you need.

Comment: Oh man I feel embarassed for having written that! Thank you for clearing that up -- I should've just immediately thought about sets for easy counterexamples of endomorphisms that don't commute..

Answer (score 3):

Requiring that the hom-sets be disjoint is an irrelevant technical condition; category theory is essentially the same the same whether or not you impose this requirement. Requiring it allows some slightly simpler approaches to the subject, but makes other approaches slightly less convenient.

If you do require hom-sets to be disjoint, there's a systematic to always guarantee that when constructing a category: you simply define $\hom(A,B)$ to be the set of all tuples of the form $(A,f,B)$ where $f$ is the kind of object you want to consider as a morphism from $A$ to $B$.

---

In the category you define (improving your definition as indicated above, if necessary), every object of $\textsf{C}^*_A$ is going to be isomorphic to every other object. In fact, there is a canonical choice of isomorphism: the one corresponding to the identity map $1_A : A \to A$.

So, $\textsf{C}^*_A$ is equivalent to the full subcategory of $\textsf{C}$ consisting of the object $A$ (and its endomorphisms), meaning that it's not a particularly interesting construction.

Comment: That's a really interesting way of getting around the fifth condition! Also, thank you for sharing that the condition isn't really necessary. I understand the category I made up is somewhat silly and not at all as worthwhile as $\textsf{C}_A$, but my main motivation for this post was whether it even was a proper category.

Comment: I do have one question though: you mention every object is isomorphic to every other object -- do you mean homomorphisms, not objects? I don't understand how it would hold for objects -- for instance if we considered $\textsf{C}=\textsf{Set}$, $A=\{ * \}$ (a singleton), then objects $\{1\} \to \{ * \}$ and $\{1,2\} \to \{ * \}$ aren't isomorphic (if we take the view that they're both sets of ordered pairs)..

Comment: @AndrewTawfeek: In the category you described, $1_A$ is a morphism from $\{1\} \to \{ * \}$ to $\{ 1,2 \} \to \{ * \}$, and $1_A$ is a morphism from $\{ 1,2 \} \to \{ * \}$ to $\{1\} \to \{ * \}$, and they are inverses. Therefore, they are isomorphic as objects of $\textsf{C}_A^*$.

Comment: My mistake -- I understand now and thank you for clarifying.

Comment: "every object is going to be isomorphic to every other object" I suppose this is true in the OP's strict formulation, noting that asking a "U-shaped" diagram $Z_1 \to A \to A \leftarrow Z_2$ to commute doesn't actually impose any extra conditions on anything, as all such diagrams (vacuously) commute. But here I would claim that this definition of 'morphism' was *unnatural*, as Aluffi used the word!